# Sql Exeption: Invalid column name "NormalizedUserName

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am new to asp.net core and I created an app with Asp.Net Core 2.2 +EF using Identity Core to create a registration page and I got this error after I ran the app and introduced some test data(email, password):

```
SqlException: Invalid column name 'NormalizedUserName'.
              Invalid column name 'AccessFailedCount'.
              Invalid column name 'ConcurrencyStamp'.
              Invalid column name 'Email'.
              Invalid column name 'EmailConfirmed'.
              Invalid column name 'LockoutEnabled'.
              Invalid column name 'LockoutEnd'.
              Invalid column name 'NormalizedEmail'.
              Invalid column name 'NormalizedUserName'.
              Invalid column name 'PasswordHash'.
              Invalid column name 'PhoneNumber'.
              Invalid column name 'PhoneNumberConfirmed'.
              Invalid column name 'SecurityStamp'.
              Invalid column name 'TwoFactorEnabled'.
              Invalid column name 'UserName'.
```

I created a table and I don't have my columns named like above (mine are "EmailAddress" and "Password" only)

Account controller(ignore the LOGIN methods):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using XmlViewer.Models;
using XmlViewer.ViewModels;

namespace XmlViewer.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]

        [HttpGet]

        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]

        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel vm)//model binding
        {
            //date din vm sunt bune:
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(vm.Email, vm.Password, vm.RememberMe, false);//folosit para pt IsPersistent(BOOL)
                if(result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Privacy", "Home");
                }
                ModelState.AddModelError("","Invalid Login. Please Check your username/email or password.");
                return View(vm);
            }
            return View(vm);
        }

        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel vm)//model binding
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = vm.Email, Email = vm.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, vm.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description); //erori de inregistrare in cont
                    }//iterare prin fiecare eroare

                }
            }
            return View(vm);
        }
    }
}
```

Context model:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;


    namespace XmlViewer.Models
    {
    public class XmlViewerContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        //constructor
        //added migration Initial-Migration:tabelul de date in DB se creeaza dupa
        public XmlViewerContext(DbContextOptions<XmlViewerContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Register").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("EmailAddress"); ;
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Register").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("Password");



        }
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using XmlViewer.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace XmlViewer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public static int Progress { get; set; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<XmlViewerContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddDbContext<XmlViewerContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source = (localdb)\ProjectsV13; Initial Catalog = XmlViewer; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30;"));
            //Alta baza de date nu master
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Register}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you applied the EF migrations to your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you scaffold `Identity` (by clicking "individual user account" in visual studio), it generates the model for you. You need to run migrations on *that model*. This will create AspNet* tables that will have the columns that you are missing. 
It looks like you created those tables manually, without the columns that Microsoft Identity expects

Comment: I would be extremely grateful if you told me how to add migration on this table(being new and all comes with consequences:)) Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please read the answer again (it helps, especially when you are new to a technology!) First, you run the migration on the *Model* - the table is the *result* of the migration. Second, more important - you *shouldn't* create identity model by hand! Choose "Individual Accounts" in Visual Studio, and the model will be created for you. Finally (and it is important) - it will be easier for you if `XmlViewrContext` is in a *different* DbContext from Identity

Comment: but how can I change my authentification to an already existing project?

Comment: The easiest way would be to scaffold *another* project, and then move stuff from one project to another

Answer (score 18):

@AlexGodo I know this topic is old, but it might help someone moving ASP.NET project to ASP.NET Core who doesn't want to use migrations and just connect to existing `AspNet*` tables.
To resolve the missing columns issue, just add them to the `AspNetUsers` table (via SSMS for eg.):

I had 4 missing columns where `NormalizedUserName` was the important one (random datatypes - TBC):

```
NormalizedUserName nvarchar(256), null
NormalizedEmail nvarchar(256), null
LockoutEnd datetime, null
ConcurrencyStamp nvarchar(256), null
```

To be able to log in, I had run the update to fill NormalizedUserName column like below:

```
update AspNetUsers
   set NormalizedUserName = UPPER(Email)
where NormalizedUserName is null
```

**Note:** After login via ASP.NET Core website `PasswordHash` column entries changes, so it won't be possible to login in via old website anymore.
(It's good idea to do a backup of this column if needed.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: To not change `PasswordHash` after login, and be able to login using ASP.NET same as ASP.NET Core you should use Identity V2, by adding this code snippet to the Startup.cs
          
`services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options =>
                options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);`